# SciPy. How i can solve differential equation?

Tags: python, scipy

I have that system is:

d2x/dt = -k/m * dx/dt, dx/dt(0) = v0_x, x(0) = 0

d2y/dt = -g - k/m * dy/dt, dy/dt(0) = v0_y, y(0) = 0

k, m, v0_x, v0_y and g is constants.

I'm do this, but i think this is a wrong, cause this is a kinematic equation and time range from 0 to 10, cannot be negative. [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07nFb.png)

```
from scipy import integrate
from math import sin, cos
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 9.81

class SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations:
    def __init__(self, k, angle, v0, m):
        self.k = k
        self.angle = angle
        self.m = m
        self.v0 = v0
        self.v0_x = self.v0 * cos(self.angle)
        self.v0_y = self.v0 * sin(self.angle)
        self.kdivm = self.k / self.m
        self.time = np.arange(0, 10, 0.05)

    def xmodel(self, X, t):
        x = X[0]
        dx = X[1]
        zdot = [ [], [] ]
        zdot[0] = dx
        zdot[1] = -self.kdivm * x
        return zdot

    def ymodel(self, Y, t):
        y = Y[0]
        dy = Y[1]
        zdot = [ [], [] ]
        zdot[0] = dy
        zdot[1] = -g - self.kdivm * y
        return zdot

    def solveX(self):
        x = integrate.odeint(self.xmodel, [0, self.v0_x], self.time)
        return x

    def solveY(self):
        y = integrate.odeint(self.ymodel, [0, self.v0_y], self.time)
        return y

k, angle, v0, m = 0.001, 60, 5, 0.1
Solver = SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations(k, angle, v0, m)
x = Solver.solveX()
y = Solver.solveY()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the following equation:

d2x/dt = -k/m * dx/dt

But in the code you set

```
zdot[1] = -self.kdivm * x
```

So there is a mismatch between what you asked for and what you programmed

Would that be a problem?

Also, if you set k to a bigger value, you are going to see a periodic oscillation... so I think your code is correct

I think you had a negative value because you are using degree instead of radians for the angle

Comment: I tried do this, but it's wrong too, i have negative x and y

Comment: Oh, I see. You have the angles in degrees instead of radians. So you have a negative velocity as the standpoint. Try to change 60 to 60/180 * 3.14

Comment: oh, i forgot that in python math uses radians. And i needed install y lim from 0 and x lim. Thanks